Environment Variables are not seen in Bash Applications
I am trying to pass a password to a Postgres db in bash on Ubuntu 22.04. like so:
export PGPASSWORD=postgrespw

when I am trying to use them in applications like so:
(for example cjdb, a program handling uploading to a PostgreSQL database, https://github.com/cityjson/cjdb:

The password can be specified in the PGPASSWORD environment variable. If not specified, the app will prompt for the password.

)
cjdb import -H localhost -U postgres -d test -s cjdb -f src/cjdb/LoD2_326625712.jsonl

or like this:
(martin, a program also handling some database function on PostgreSQL db)
martin --config config.yaml

I always get "missing password".
using psql directly strangely works:
psql -U postgres testcjdb -h localhost

both of the mentioned programs clearly state that they support the use of the env variable PGPASSWORD
How can I figure out if it's the programs fault (which I kind of don't believe), or if something is off with my bash terminal?

For cjdb it looks like it just doesn't recognize the environment variable.

On Linux, the easy way to test whether it's getting the variable and ignoring it, vs not getting the variable at all, is to find the PID of one of these processes and run and tr '\0' '\n' </proc/PID/environ | grep -e PGPASSWORD, replacing the string PID with the actual number. If it shows up there, it's not bash's problem but instead is an issue with cjdb or martin (neither of which I've heard of before despite working in several Postgres shops) and is something you should bring to their authors.

Of course, you can also run declare -p PGPASSWORD in the same shell you're subsequently going to start cjdb from (if you're not starting it from a shell at all but using a GUI, that points to a completely different problem); if you get a response starting with declare -- that tells us the variable isn't exported, if you get one starting with declare -x it means it is, if you get an error saying the variable isn't set at all, of course, that means what it says.

@tjm3772 that was my own PR for my problem. but now that i have the same problem again with Martin, i kind of doubt that its their problem, but rather my problem ;)

@CharlesDuffy i do get: declare -x PGPASSWORD="postgrespw"

@CharlesDuffy thanks for your first comment too! i do get this tho: tr '\0' '\n' </proc/1957428/environ | grep -e PGPASSWORD PGPASSWORD=postgrespw
so i guess it could actually use the env variable.

nod, both those results tell us bash is doing the right thing. (The PR against cjdb actually fixes cjdb, right? If bash wasn't passing the environment variable to the application, it wouldn't be in os.environ so the PR wouldn't work).

BTW, consider PGPASSWORD='secure' application arg1 arg2 ... instead of export PGPASSWORD='secure'; application arg1 arg2 ... -- the former way still exports the variable, but only for the one application, without leaving it in the environment for everything else later started by the same shell.

If it weren't the program's fault, the PR you wrote wouldn't work; the fact that that PR addresses the problem is in and of itself proof that the environment variable is being passed to the program but the program is ignoring it (as if the variable weren't passed, 'PGPASSWORD' in os.environ would be false).
Further means you can prove this to your own satisfaction:

Given the PID of a running program, you can read a NUL-delimited stream of the environment variables defined for that program from /proc/PID/environ. Use tr '\0' '\n' to change the NUL delimiters to newlines for easier human readability, or to make sure every variable is readably printed:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
(( $# )) || { echo "Usage: $0 pid [pid2] ..." >&2; exit 1; }
for pid in "$@"; do
  while IFS= read -r -d '' entry; do
    var=${entry%%=*}
    value=${entry#*=}
    printf '%s=%q\n' "$var" "$value"
  done <"/proc/$pid/environ"
done

...can be passed a PID (or list of them), and will dump environment variables' values in printable form even if they contain newlines or other nonprinting characters.

In the shell, declare -p varname will emit declare -- varname=... if a string-type variable is not exported (arrays will have declare -a, integers declare -i, namevars declare -n, etc); or declare -x varname=... if it is (or write an error if the variable is not set at all).


